# Symfony2 and FormBuilder: How to get the elemetns number added in the builder

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig

I have a formbuilder where I am adding some values from an entity:

```
$builder->add('affiliation', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'SciForumVersion2Bundle:UserAffiliation',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($author,$user) {
     return $er->createQueryBuilder('ua')
        ->where("ua.user_id = {$user->getId()}")
        ->andWhere("ua.affiliation_id not in ( select pa.affiliation_id FROM SciForumVersion2Bundle:PersonAffiliation pa where pa.person_id = {$author->getPersonId()} )");
     },
     'required'  => true,
));
```

In my controller, I would like to check if there is something in my form. If there is something, I will display one view, if there is nothing, I will display another view.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "check if there is something in my form?" What exactly are you looking for? What are you basing the condition on?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @ColinMorelli. In fact, I am populating the builder from an entity with 2 where clauses. If the query returns something, this will be added in the builder. In my controlelr I would liek to know if the query returned something, so if there is at least an element the form.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try it:

```
$data = $form->getData()
```

[function getData() documentation Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

Comment: Thank you 0x1gene, but I am alvays getting the same think: `object(SciForum\Version2Bundle\Entity\PersonAffiliation)#567 (5) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["person_id":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["affiliation_id":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["person":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["affiliation":protected]=>
  NULL
}`

Comment: is it when you are rendering the form or when you are submitting it  that you whant to know what is inside ? Also, did you check that your query return some results in your case ?

Comment: Maybe try : `$form->get('affiliation')->getData();`

Comment: I am trying to check my form when rendering, not when submiting. Depending on the form, I would liek to render different view. My query is returning the right result.

Comment: For your last comment, I tryed that but this works only when the form is submitted and I would liek to know what Is in the form before.

Comment: hum sorry i'm out of ideas :( In other hand you could get the query from your controller directly and check the result

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing for the moment, but I though that instead executing the same query twice, I could do it once in the form builder and then only check my form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current data (just after rendering the form) in your form type you can use the `builder` supplied in each form type by standard.

It works exactly as a normal form response, so you can use:

`$builder->getData();`

and use if clauses to add different fields depending on what you want to generate.

Comment: Could you provide more details please, what is the $builder ?

Comment: You used the builder in you own questions code. It basically is the object that contains all your formtypes data.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. What if my builder is created in a FormType class? How could I get the $builder in the controler?